# Get very first week day of a new month in carbon php

Tags: php, php-carbon

Hello please i am having problem in getting the start week date of next month using php carbon.
I try the below code with out the start of the current month not the added month.

```
$carbon = new Carbon();
$thisMonth = $carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
$nextMonth = $thisMonth->addMonth();
echo $nextMonth->startOfWeek();
```

Out put of the above code

> 2020-09-28 00:00:00

Expectation:
Today is 27 - 09 2020 i expected to output the first week day of the next month with is 01 - 10 -2020.

I need to get the first date (Monday - Friday) of every next month from the current month when execute this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get First Date of Every Next Month, you can try this:

```
now()->addMonthNoOverflow(1)->firstOfMonth()->dayName;
```

Comment: I want to get the first date of the money that is why I use weekday so it can get from Monday to dirday. If the first week is 2 it get 2 - 10 2020 that what am trying to